# Where should window.open be in Redux data flow?

Tags: redux

I have an async call in a middleware that looks like this:

```
myApi.postToResource(info).then((response) => {
 window.open(response.url);
}).catch((error) => {
 // Handle error
});

next(action);
```

I have a feeling that I should be dispatching an action instead of straight doing `window.open(url)`, but I don't know at which point I should be opening the URL. I don't think it should be in a reducer, so trying to wonder where that should happen.